# Unable to obtain exclusive access when adding a check constraint

Tags: informix

I have encountered a problem with in one of my Informix environments, I can't get an exclusive lock on a table to add a check constraint.

> ### Error message
>
> SQL Error (-242): Could not open database table ().
>   ISAM error: non-exclusive access.

My first thought was that there was a session using the table so I waited to the end of the day to minimize usage and tried again with the same result.
I then checked for locks on that table but there aren't any locks at all on that table, in fact there are no locks at all in that database right now.
I then turned of replication on the table but the problem is still there.
Now I'm all out of ideas on how to solve this, I'd rather not restart the server or kill all the sessions connected to it.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved the problem.
There were some sessions with dirty read that had got stuck waiting to read from the table.
Since a knew the table name I could get the hexadecimal partnum from systables with

```
SELECT HEX(partnum) FROM systables where tabname = <table>
```

I then used *onstat -g opn | grep*  to get the thread ids (first column called tid in the result) connected to the table.
From there i could use *onstat -g ath | grep*  to get the rsam thread control block address(third column rtscb in the result, in the fifth column you can se the status) and use it with *onstat -u | grep*  to get the session id (third column in the result called sessid).
I then just used the session id with *onmode -z*  to kill the active sessions

Answer (score 1):

Great answer - also worth checking the following

```
onstat -g stm | grep -E "TABLENAME|^session"
```

This checks the prepared SQL statement cache and will return all sessions and any mention of your TABLENAME

```
session 79412526   ----------------------------------------------------------

session 79412418   ----------------------------------------------------------

session 79412200   ----------------------------------------------------------

c00000042e5eeff0 30624       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME

session 79411988   ----------------------------------------------------------

c0000004167b1230 30624       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME

session 79411978   ----------------------------------------------------------
```

I have of course masked the data from our environment but you should get the drift.